# Braintree - paymentMethodNonceReceived not being invoked

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway, braintree

I have setup dropin UI for braintree. I can see the UI fine. Before that I created the customer and I can see the customer on braintree-sandbox. Now I want to add payment method to the customer. I am trying following code, but paymentMethodNonceReceived is not being invoked. Not sure why.

```
braintree.setup("<?=CLIENT_TOKEN_FROM_PHP?>", 
    "dropin", 
    {
      container: "divBrainTreeContainer",
      paymentMethodNonceReceived: function (event, nonce) {
        console.log(nonce);
        $('#formProfile').append('<input type="hidden" name="payment_method_nonce" value="'+nonce+'" />');
        $('#formProfile').submit();
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: I work at Braintree on the SDK team.

Do you have the `divBraintTreeContainer` element inside of a `form` element? If so, does that `form` contain a submit button?

Comment: Ok @kdetella thanks, there was no submit button, I was submitting via javascript, but when I added the submit button, I got the payment_method_nonce.

Comment: @kdetella This fact about the submit button is not indicated anywhere on either the drop-in UI page or the Hello, Client page. It would be great to add this somewhere, as I was stumped by this too!  It does not prevent a nonce coming down on a custom UI.

Comment: @kdetella I would humbly suggest adding this to your documentation, because I just spent half a day trying to figure out why the callback was never called. More generally, though, forms are a thing of the past. I had to dig out info on how submit button markup looks like. Also, I'd much rather have a function that I can call that will initiate payment and call me back when done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per @kdetella's comment, there should be a `submit` button inside the `<form>` element to receive payment method nonce.

Comment: I am using braintree with js, I have added submit button inside the div id which I have mentioned in the container, but still I am unable to get nonce ,instead getting Uncaught Error: Could not stringify event: JSON.stringify is not a function

Answer (score 7):

I am using below **JavaScript** and its **working fine**:

```
  braintree.setup(clientToken, "custom", {
    id: "my-sample-form",
    hostedFields: {
      number: {
        selector: "#card-number"
      },
      cvv: {
        selector: "#cvv"
      },
      expirationMonth: {
        selector: "#expiration-month"
      },
      expirationYear: {
        selector: "#expiration-year"
      },
    },onPaymentMethodReceived:function(nonce){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(nonce));
        return false;

  }
    }

          );
```

**Above gives below response and DOES NOT submit the form:**

```
{"nonce":"ff2662e1-f1fd-42a3-a16f-d8f3213a2406","details":{"lastTwo":"11","cardType":"Visa"},"type":"CreditCard"}
```

means use **onPaymentMethodReceived** instead of **paymentMethodNonceReceived**

Thanks 
http://www.web-technology-experts-notes.in/2015/06/braintree-payment-gateway-integration.html

Comment: I am using braintree with js, I have added submit button inside the div id which I have mentioned in the container, but still I am unable to get nonce ,instead getting Uncaught Error: Could not stringify event: JSON.stringify is not a function. Please help

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/issues/58

For custom integration with multiple payment method, use onSuccess instead of onPaymentMethodReceived.

```
braintree.setup(TOKEN, 'custom', {
  id: 'checkout',
  paypal: {
    container: 'paypal-container',
    onSuccess: function (nonce, email) {
      // This will be called as soon as the user completes the PayPal flow
      // nonce:String
      // email: String
    }
  },
  onPaymentMethodReceived: function(obj) {
    // This will be called when the user submits the form
  }
});
```

Comment: `OnSuccess` has been [deprecated](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/paypal#options)